# Create a new column based on logical operation on multiple columns

Tags: pandas

Struggling with this one! I want to create a new dataframe column based on a logical OR over a number of columns.

The dataframe is of the form:

```
    apples    bananas    oranges
0             bananas
1   apples
2
3                        oranges
4
5             bananas    oranges
```

(The blanks in the columns are NaNs). I want to create a new column which indicates whether fruit is mentioned or not (doesn't matter how many times it's been mentioned). So I end up with this:

```
    apples    bananas    oranges    fruit
0             bananas               fruit 
1   apples                          fruit
2
3                        oranges    fruit
4
5             bananas    oranges    fruit
```

To me, it looks like a logical OR on the first three columns, but I just can't work out how to do that.

Comment: So what is present as missing values in the columns as this matters, ie. blank string, `NaN` etc...

Comment: The blanks are NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if empty values are `NaN`:

```
df.loc[df.notnull().any(1), 'new'] = 'fruit'
print (df)
   apples  bananas  oranges    new
0     NaN  bananas      NaN  fruit
1  apples      NaN      NaN  fruit
2     NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
3     NaN      NaN  oranges  fruit
4     NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
5     NaN  bananas  oranges  fruit
```

Or if empty values are empty strings use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with changed mask:

```
df[ 'new'] = np.where((df != '').any(1), 'fruit', '')
print (df)
   apples  bananas  oranges    new
0          bananas           fruit
1  apples                    fruit
2                                 
3                   oranges  fruit
4                                 
5          bananas  oranges  fruit
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: How would `df.loc[df.notnull().any(1), 'new'] = 'fruit'` change if I only wanted to include the apples and bananas columns?

Comment: Then use subset `df.loc[df[['apples','bananas']].notnull().any(1), 'new'] = 'fruit'`

Comment: Glad can help you. You can also upvote my solution, thanks.